# Overwrite function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.7

TypeScript: [view on playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F%2Fdeclare%20function%20alert(...messages%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%0Aalert%20%3D%20(function%20(orig)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(...messages%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20orig(messages.join(%22%20%22))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)(alert)%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20This%20would%20work%2C%20but%20defines%20another%20variable%0Aconst%20oldAlert%20%3D%20alert%0Afunction%20alert(...messages%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%20%0A%09oldAlert(messages.join(%22%20%22))%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Example%0Aalert(1%2C%202)%0A)

```
alert = (function (origAlert) {
    return function (...messages: any[]) {
        origAlert(messages.join(" "))
    }
})(alert)

// Example
alert(1, 2)
```

I want to overwrite / redefine the function `alert(message?: any)` wich has already been declared in `lib.d.ts` before: `declare function alert(message?: any): void;`

But `alert = function...` throws "*`Invalid left-hand side of assignment expression.`*"

The point is that, `function alert(...messages: any[]) { /* ... */ }` <s>would work</s>* does not even work aswell, but I need to use the original `alert`. And I'd dislike to define an extra `const origAlert = alert` before the function.

How can I do this?

---

Note that the compiled JavaScript in the Playground works as intended.

*on TypeScript Playground it works, but in Visual Studio it throws "*`Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient`*"

Comment: I don't know what the intended use of your code is. However, if you need it for debugging, then I would just use `console.log()`. Otherwise, it's a bad idea to redefine native functions, often it backfires.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare function alert(...messages: any[]): void;

window.alert = ((orig) => {
    return (...messages: any[]) => orig(messages.join(" "));
})(alert);

alert(1, 2)
```

Comment: That hack works for this, thanks^^ I'll still hope someone can find a general solution

Comment: these error messages is not clear enough - look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2474.

I doubt that someone will make a general solution. 

P.S. I hope that I am wrong)

Comment: Also Playground is compiling it just as it should.. that's really strange

Comment: The compiler will output results even if there are transpilation errors, the flag `noEmitOnError` changes this behaviour.

Comment: It's compiled because of this hack do not owerwrites original lib.d.ts file 


`declare function alert(message?: any): void; // this stuff`

following code tries to overwrite declare function like it's a variable

`alert = function(/**/){/**/}`

So, hacks is our everything.

PS Sorry for engrish.