# Overwrite a global JavaScript function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript, I can overwrite a function:

```
function testf() {
    console.log('old function')
}
testf = function() {
    console.log("new function");
}
```

How can I do this in TypeScript? I'm writing a WebP polyfill and would like to overwrite the global `createImageBitmap` function, but *tsc* complains:

*Cannot assign to 'createImageBitmap' because it is not a variable.*

Comment: @musefan the first result is the current question

Comment: @bugs: I have no idea how I managed to copy the wrong link... I [meant this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238497/overwrite-function-in-typescript)

Comment: you have to tell your compiler which global variables you are using. I believe there is preset to use browser globals and otherwise write your own d.ts -typing files and declare your globals that tslint can understand them. otherwise typescript is just normal javascript so your code will work even though your editor displays this error.

Comment: @musefan I'm sorry, I didn't found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238497/overwrite-function-in-typescript) with Google before when I searched for my problem. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Don't delete it. At the worst, this one can just be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @FabianHeller: Well... does the other question solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `someName = whatever` requires that `someName` is defined within the current scope as a variable.

You can, however, assign to `window` (same as assigning the variable of any other object), which should produce the same effect:

```
window.createImageBitmap = customImageBitmap
```

Just make sure `customImageBitmap` has the same signature (argument types and return types) as `window.createImageBitmap` in order for this to pass the type checker.

Comment: The solution is to assign to `window` (together with the `declare function ...`). I tried it without `window`, therefore it didn't worked.

Comment: The `declare function ...` is not needed. [See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20const%20dummyImageBitmap%3A%20ImageBitmap%0D%0A%0D%0Awindow.createImageBitmap%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise.resolve(dummyImageBitmap)%0D%0A)